# Razor Partial with Model from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Settings Action on my Account controller that renders the Settings View.

On the Settings View, I recieve a ViewModel that includes ChangePasswordModel.

Here is the SettingsViewModel:

```
public class SettingsViewModel
{
    public ChangePasswordModel ChangePasswordModel { get; set; }
}
```

The Settings View recieves

```
@model XBLTools.Models.SettingsViewModel
```

The ChangePassword View recieves

```
@model XBLTools.Models.ChangePasswordModel
```

The ChangePassword view works OK alone.
How to render the ChangePassword View passing the Model.ChangePasswordModel?

I've tried some combinations without success getting different errors:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("ChangePassword", (XBLTools.Models.ChangePasswordModel)(Model.ChangePasswordModel))

@Html.RenderPartial("ChangePassword", Model.ChangePasswordModel)

@Html.Partial("ChangePassword", (XBLTools.Models.ChangePasswordModel)(Model.ChangePasswordModel))

@Html.Partial("ChangePassword", Model.ChangePasswordModel)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is you ChangePasswordModel null?

Comment: Yes it is. It is the first time the Settings view is rendered.

Comment: `@Html.RenderPartial("ChangePassword", Model.ChangePasswordModel)` Should work fine, can you post the error you get when using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's null pass in a new instance of ChangePasswordModel:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("ChangePassword", new ChangePasswordModel())
```

Or instantiate it in the constructor of SettingsViewModel:

```
public class SettingsViewModel
{
    public SetttingsViewModel() 
    {
        ChangePasswordModel = new ChangePasswordModel();
    }
    public ChangePasswordModel ChangePasswordModel { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass your model property:

```
@Html.Partial("ChangePassword", Model.ChangePasswordModel)
```

If the `ChangePasswordModel` proeprty is `null`, you'll get an error, since the partial view needs a model.
Make sure that you've set the `ChangePasswordModel` property to an instance.

Alternatively, you can just pass a new `ChangePasswordModel` instance:

```
@Html.Partial("ChangePassword", new ChangePasswordModel())
```

Comment: It says: "error CS0118: 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model is a property but is used like a type"

Comment: Sorry; I misunderstood.  You can just pass the model property.  Note that the property can't be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialise the ChangePasswordModel on the settings view model in the controller.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{

   var model = new SettingsViewModel{
          ChangePasswordModel = new ChangePasswordModel()
       }
   return View(model);

}
```

then use:

```
@Html.Partial("ChangePassword", Model.ChangePasswordModel)
```

Comment: This works. I had to remove the parameter (SettingsViewModel model) that Settings action was recieving too. Maybe the "initial action" doesn't need to recieve a model, just render empty. Is that right?